# Zend Framework 2 and Doctrine change database per module

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have an application which use Zend Framework and Doctrine. 
I want to change for a module the database from the default settings.

I have created an alternative connection for doctrine.
When creating/updating the tables using,

```
./vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:update --force
```

the tables are created in the first configuration of database.

Basically what I want to update the second configured database tables.

Can someone help me with an working example ?

Thanks,
Bogdan

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, the schema-tool binary only works with the orm_default database.

Now, there's certainly nothing stopping you from having modules that add additional named connections. See this documentation for doing that:

https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule/blob/master/docs/configuration.md#how-to-use-two-connections

But, the tooling around managing those additional databases might be a little "roll your own". The good news is all the pieces are there (Doctrine's underlying SchemaTool classes), you would just need to wire them up and build a cli command that acts on multiple schemas.

All that being said, if you find yourself using multiple unique schemas in the same database engine (unique being the key word to account for things like doctrine sharding), I worry your application design might be potentially troublesome. It could be possible that your multiple storage domains should actually live as separate applications.

Comment: Thanks Tim for your answer. The alternative connection work's fine from the controller. I can choose from there which entity manager I need. But when creating/updating the database schema orm it's using the default connection. The business requirements are that the configuration table and data table should be in separate databases and that's why I need two databases. So the question remain: how can I change the database in the orm_default settings for an module .